# UDP Packet Analysis

Tags: java, networking

So, for a specific task I am asked to search and print the

> request and response (for protocol fields)

for captured **UDP DNS packets**.

Now I am very new to network programming and I tried to achieve this using the [JNetPcap Library](http://jnetpcap.com). However, please note that the question is **not** about [JNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com) functions.

The sample outputs I am getting from my program (which can be modified) is viz.

```
Got UDP Packet
Name of packet :Udp
The Source :14786
The Destination :53
The Legnth of packet :8

Got UDP Packet
Name of packet :Udp
The Source :58186
The Destination :53
The Legnth of packet :8
```

So **what is the** `request and response` **here**? If my output is incomplete, what fields do I need to print to get the request and response?

**Edit:** I am not sniffing any specific application. I am asked to sniff the network (as in, run in your software in our machine and that's all) as a whole and find the request and response.
Thanks.

**Extra Information That May Be Relevant:**

So to filter UDP DNS packets I am using this code (**the code may not be required for the question**, but I am including it just in case I have done something wrong):

```
PcapBpfProgram program = new PcapBpfProgram();
String expression = "udp dst port 53";
int optimize = 0;         // 0 = false
int netmask = 0xFFFFFF00; // 255.255.255.0
if (pcap.compile(program, expression, optimize, netmask) != Pcap.OK) {
                System.err.println(pcap.getErr());
                return;
}
```

Here I analyze the first 10 packets viz.

```
// Receive packet from the loop
PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = packet_handler();
// capture first 10 packages
pcap.loop(10, jpacketHandler, "");
```

And this is how I print the sample output given above:

```
public static PcapPacketHandler<String> packet_handler() {
PcapPacketHandler<String> jpacketHandler = new PcapPacketHandler<String>() {
Udp udp = new Udp();

@Override
public void nextPacket(PcapPacket packet, String user) {

// Another check to determine if packet is UDP.
if (!packet.hasHeader(udp)) {
   // not UDP? skip
}
// Yet another check to determine if packet is UDP.
if (packet.hasHeader(udp)) {
    System.out.println("Got UDP Packet");
    System.out.println("Name of packet :" + packet.getHeader(udp).getName());
    System.out.println("The Source :" + packet.getHeader(udp).source());
    System.out.println("The Destination :" + packet.getHeader(udp).destination());
    System.out.println("The Check sum :" + packet.getHeader(udp).checksum());
    System.out.println("The Legnth of packet :" + packet.getHeader(udp).getHeaderLength());
```

Comment: You are not getting complete DNS packets - in fact if those 8 bytes are just the UDP header then you're not getting any DNS payload at all.  The smallest legal DNS payload is 12 bytes (per RFC 1035)

Comment: Ah, looking at your code you're printing the wrong value - your string says you're printing the length of the packet, but you're actually printing the UDP header length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to fix your pcap filter by removing the `dst` qualifier so that you see both packets *to and from* port 53:

```
String expression = "udp port 53";
```

Then, and most importantly, you need to read [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), especially §4.

Requests and responses are identified by the `QR` bit, which is the most significant bit of the 3rd octet of the DNS payload.

To actually match requests and responses then for each packet you need to remember the tuple of (*source ip*, *source port*, *dest ip*, *dest port*, *DNS query ID*), not forgetting that in response packets the source and destination values will be reversed.

In most cases you should also check that the `QNAME` in the response matches the one seen in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me as if you got two requests only. You appearently filtered only for destination port 53:

```java
String expression = "udp dst port 53";
```

Resonses should be coming from the same port, so you need to additionally filter for this one, too (`"udp src port 53"`).

*Edit according to the comments (thanks to Alnitak):*

The right filter then should be `"udp port 53"`.

Comment: if it's standard pcap then just `udp port 53` would do.

Comment: It uses `libpcap` so I think it should be same.

Comment: @jeet it does appear that way - I've not used the Java bindings but they do look like they're a straight wrapper around libpcap